TPM не включается что делать?
Включаю тпм  с discrete tpm на firmware tpm в биосе(проц интел)(плата асус) и при перезагрузке все возвращается в стадию discrete tpm

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Что такое на самом деле "включаю". Надо ещё и сохранить результаты на выходе. Думаю, стоит почитать эту допинформацию:
Discrete TPM
Discrete TPM (дискретный TPM) представляет собой отдельный микрочип, который устанавливается на материнскую плату компьютера. Этот чип выполняет функции, связанные с безопасностью, такие как генерация и хранение криптографических ключей, проверка целостности системы и управление доступом к данным. Дискретные TPM-чипы обеспечивают высокий уровень безопасности, так как они физически изолированы от других компонентов системы.

Firmware TPM
Firmware TPM (прошивочный TPM) реализуется в виде программного обеспечения, встроенного в микропроцессор или чипсет компьютера. Это позволяет использовать те же функции безопасности, что и дискретный TPM, но без необходимости установки отдельного чипа. Firmware TPM использует ресурсы процессора и памяти системы, что может быть менее безопасным, чем дискретный TPM, но все же обеспечивает достаточный уровень защиты для большинства пользователей.

Основные различия
Уровень безопасности: Дискретный TPM обеспечивает более высокий уровень безопасности благодаря физической изоляции от других компонентов системы.
Установка: Дискретный TPM требует установки отдельного чипа на материнскую плату, тогда как firmware TPM встроен в микропроцессор или чипсет.
Производительность: Firmware TPM использует ресурсы системы, что может немного снижать производительность по сравнению с дискретным TPM.
